# How to process document state transition?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, finite-state-machine

Imagine there is an *application* (`ASP.NET MVC`) that processes some documents. The `document` must be revised several times by *different group of users*.

state/role rules:

- **simple user** can only **publish** document; (priority: **low**)
- **userGroup1** can switch it to **next state** or **reject** it; (priority: **higher**)
- **userGroup2** can **confirm** previous state and switch it to **next gradual** state or **reject** it; (priority: **highest**)

  1. How to implement such a workflow in `ASP.NET MVC`? How to impelement `UI`, `views` so that group with lower priority can both visually/technically perform only `allowed transitions`? Can I somehow extend that system: [link](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/02/19/ASPNET-MVC-5-Identity-Implementing-Group-Based-Permissions-Management-Part-II.aspx)?
  2. Do I need extras like service bus, event sourcing for that?

[image]

Comment: Do the members of higher priority groups have permissions to perform the same actions as lower priority groups?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman yes.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar
Created a class user
And an enumeration role
HashSet of the roles the user is in

Create a public property for each authority

```
public bool CanPublish
{
    get { return roles.Contains(role.simple) || roles.Contains(role.Group1) ...; }
}
```

This gives you the freedom to add or remove roles and what roles have have what authority
The UI is not in the business of deciding what role can do what